# A question about properties of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: let a be n*n matrix and λ be scalar then λ is eigenvalue of A iff (A-λI)X=0 has non tirival solution]

---

**My attempt**

Suppose det(A-$\lambda$)=0 then then matrix is singular A-$\lambda$I=0
and then null(A-$\lambda$I)$\neq {0}$ and hence the system has non trivial solution but how to prove $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **apply** the very  meaning of the fact $\;\ker(A-\lambda I)\neq\{0\}\;$ , so there is

$$0\neq v\in V\;\;s.t.\;\;(A-\lambda I)v=0\implies Av-\lambda Iv=0\implies Av=\lambda v$$

and this means $\;v\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;A\;$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio..what is best way ti start this question form (a) to (e) or some other choices

Comment: @suresh It all depends on how you did study that. One thing must be clear: a scalar $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix (or linear operator) $\;A\;$ iff the matrix (operator) $\;A-\lambda I\;$ is **singular** ...

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do this is as follows:

> **(a) $\Rightarrow$ (b):** If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $(A-\lambda I_n)x =0$ has a non-trivial solution.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, the for some non-zero column vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ , $$Av= \lambda v \Rightarrow AI_n v = \lambda I_n v$$$$(A-\lambda I_n) v = 0$$ which precisely means that $v$ is a non-trivial solution to the equation $(A-\lambda I_n)x =0$.

> **(b) $\Rightarrow$ (c):** If $(A-\lambda I_n)x =0$ has a non-trivial solution, then $\text{null}(A-\lambda I_n) \neq \{0\}$

Obvious. Since there is not only the trivial solution, the nullity does not just contain the $0$ vector.

> **(c) $\Rightarrow$ (d):** If $\text{null}(A-\lambda I_n) \neq \{0\}$, $A -\lambda I_n$ is singular.

Let $T$ be the linear map corresponding to $(A-\lambda I)$. Since $\text{null} (T) >0$, $\text{rank} T<n$, so the map is singular. And so the matrix is singular.

> **(d) $\Rightarrow$ (e):** If $A -\lambda I_n$ is singular, then $\det(A-\lambda I_n) = 0$

Suppose $A-\lambda I_n$ is in RREF. Elementary row operations do not affect whether $\det(A-\lambda I_n)=0$. If $A- \lambda I_n$ singular, then it has some zero rows. So $\det(A - \lambda I_n) = 0$.

> **(e) $\Rightarrow$ (a):** If $\det(A-\lambda I_n) = 0$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

If $\det(A-\lambda I_n)=0$, then $A- \lambda I_n$ is singular. So the system $(A-\lambda I_n) x = 0$ admits a non-zero solution, i.e. there exists a non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ with $(A-\lambda I_n) v=0$, i.e. $Av = \lambda v$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$.

Hence they are equivalent.